# Netezza Convert UTC/GMT to Central with Daylight Savings Time

Tags: netezza

I am working in a Netezza database that stores time as GMT (or so I am told by our data engineers). I need to be able to convert this to Central Standard Time (CST) but accounting for daylight savings time. I found that I could use something like:

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'CST' AT TIME ZONE 'GMT'
```

However, when I run this SELECT (keep in mind, today is March 30, 2021 - CST should only be 5 hours different from GTM), I get a 6 hour difference.... I looked up a reference to see what time zones are available in Netezza and I see a "CDT" which is 5 hours, and that works for the 5 hour difference, but this means in my query I would need to either change this each time DST switches over or do some sort of elaborate case statement to know which one to use depending on the date/time of year.

Is there an easy automated way to convert a GTM time to Central Standard Time accounting for daylight savings time? Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question can be interpreted one of two ways. In both cases, the solution is to determine the timezone to convert to, based on whether the timestamp is between 2 AM 2nd Sunday of March and 2 AM on 1st Sunday of Nov (for US Central timezone)

1. The timestamps in your table, need to be converted to `CST` or `CDT` based on the current time (when the query is being run)

   - this means if the same query was run in Feb, the results would be different than if its run *now*
   - also it would be different based on what the timezone of the netezza system is set to

Eg

```sql
select 
  t as original, 
  -- extract year from current date and 2nd Sunday of March
  -- use last_day to make sure we account for March 1 being a Sunday
  (next_day(next_day(
           last_day((date_part('years', current_date) || '-02-01'):: date), 
        'sun'), 
      'sun')|| ' 02:00:00'):: timestamp as dstart, 
  -- extract year from current date and 1st Sunday of Nov
  -- use last_day to make sure we account for Nov 1 being a Sunday
  (next_day(last_day(
        (date_part('years', current_date) || '-10-01')::date), 
      'sun')|| ' 02:00:00'):: timestamp as dend, 
  case when current_timestamp between dstart 
  and dend then 'CDT' else 'CST' end as tz, 
  t at time zone tz as converted 
from 
  tdata;
```

will produce

```
      ORIGINAL       |       DSTART        |        DEND         | TZ  |       CONVERTED
---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----+------------------------
 2021-01-01 17:00:00 | 2021-03-14 02:00:00 | 2021-11-07 02:00:00 | CDT | 2021-01-01 12:00:00-05
 2021-04-01 17:00:00 | 2021-03-14 02:00:00 | 2021-11-07 02:00:00 | CDT | 2021-04-01 12:00:00-05
 2020-04-01 17:00:00 | 2021-03-14 02:00:00 | 2021-11-07 02:00:00 | CDT | 2020-04-01 12:00:00-05
 2020-12-01 17:00:00 | 2021-03-14 02:00:00 | 2021-11-07 02:00:00 | CDT | 2020-12-01 12:00:00-05
(4 rows)
```

OR

2. The timestamps in your table need to be converted to `CST` or `CDT` depending on when the daylight savings started/ended in the respective `year` as defined in the time stamp.

   - this is more deterministic

```sql
select 
  t as original, 
  -- extract year from this timestamp and 2nd Sunday of March
  -- use last_day to make sure we account for March 1 being a Sunday
  (next_day(next_day(
           last_day((date_part('years', t) || '-02-01'):: date), 'sun'), 
      'sun')|| ' 02:00:00'):: timestamp as dstart, 
  -- extract year from this timestamp and 1st Sunday of Nov
  -- use last_day to make sure we account for Nov 1 being a Sunday
  (next_day(last_day((date_part('years', t) || '-10-01')::date), 
      'sun')|| ' 02:00:00'):: timestamp as dend, 
  case when current_timestamp between dstart 
  and dend then 'CDT' else 'CST' end as tz, 
  t at time zone tz as converted 
from 
  tdata;
```

This will produce (tdata is a sample table w/ 4 timestamps)

```
      ORIGINAL       |       DSTART        |        DEND         | TZ  |       CONVERTED
---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----+------------------------
 2021-01-01 17:00:00 | 2021-03-14 02:00:00 | 2021-11-07 02:00:00 | CST | 2021-01-01 11:00:00-06
 2021-04-01 17:00:00 | 2021-03-14 02:00:00 | 2021-11-07 02:00:00 | CDT | 2021-04-01 12:00:00-05
 2020-04-01 17:00:00 | 2020-03-08 02:00:00 | 2020-11-01 02:00:00 | CDT | 2020-04-01 12:00:00-05
 2020-12-01 17:00:00 | 2020-03-08 02:00:00 | 2020-11-01 02:00:00 | CST | 2020-12-01 11:00:00-06
(4 rows)
```

Comment: I understand the two solutions, but is there a reason I'd want to use one over the other? Positives / Negatives? The timestamps are for when alerts are created so I need to be able to feed the CST version into a report so our analyst know that it was created at that time CST. Obviously DLST is important here due to the hour differences at different times of the year. Any suggestions which would be more appropriate to use?

Comment: Actually, now that I look at this, the former works exactly like what I want... :) This is great!

Answer (score 1):

```
system.admin(admin)=> select '2021-04-07 11:00:00' as gmt, timezone('2021-04-07 11:00:00' , 'GMT', 'America/New_York') as eastern, timezone('2021-04-07 11:00:00', 'GMT', 'America/Chicago') as central, timezone('2021-04-07 11:00:00', 'GMT', 'America/Los_Angeles') as pacific;
         gmt         |       eastern       |       central       |       pacific
---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------
 2021-04-07 11:00:00 | 2021-04-07 07:00:00 | 2021-04-07 06:00:00 | 2021-04-07 04:00:00
(1 row)

system.admin(admin)=> select '2021-03-07 11:00:00' as gmt, timezone('2021-03-07 11:00:00' , 'GMT', 'America/New_York') as eastern, timezone('2021-03-07 11:00:00', 'GMT', 'America/Chicago') as central, timezone('2021-03-07 11:00:00', 'GMT', 'America/Los_Angeles') as pacific;
         gmt         |       eastern       |       central       |       pacific
---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------
 2021-03-07 11:00:00 | 2021-03-07 06:00:00 | 2021-03-07 05:00:00 | 2021-03-07 03:00:00
(1 row)
```

Instead of CDT and CST if we use 'America/Chicago' as shown above it takes care of daylight savings.